# Send a ResultSet over Socket

Tags: java, sockets, ms-access, resultset

I am trying to create a distributed system in which the GUI will reside on a clerk's PC and the `.mdb` will reside on another PC which will act as the server.

I want to know how I can send a query from the client to the server and retrieve the `ResultSet` and populate a `JTable` on the client GUI using Socket

#### Initial Thoughts

I initially thought of using `GSON` to send data from client to server and vice versia but do not know how to and if it will be the right approach?

Comment: characters not displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send `ResultSet` object accross network using `Socket` because `ResultSet` does not implements `Serializable`. If you want to populate the `JTable` with the results obtained from `ResultSet` you should first retrieve the results from it and store in and `ArrayList` or any other `Collection` suitable for you and then send the object of that `Collection` accross network to other end via `Socket`.

Comment: So basically, make a `Vector<>` and then serialize it using `GSON` ??

Comment: Why using `GSON`? `java.util.Vector` is itself serializable. Just fill up the vector with data from `ResultSet` and send across the network to other end by `Socket` using `writeObject` method of `ObjectOutputStream` .And read the `Vector` back over other end using `readObject` method of `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can do it with [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)

Though I'd recommend a layer of abstraction

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to send Query just send a number or a flag which corresponds to particular Query like when user click on the GUI for display send #1 to server for display for insert #2 and so on.. 
and from server to get the Resultset is quite tricky.

I am facing the same situation where i need to read from database and send Resultset to the client but to send objects over network you need ObjectOutputStream which only work if the object you are sending is of the class which implements Serialiazble but in your case Resultset does not implements Serializable so a solution is

create a user defined class and implement serializable on it then read the Resultset contents into the object of this class and the send this data over the Stream you can send data like this i tried it and it worked for me .